# Acceso a archivos en VS - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Colegas, tengo el siguiente problema: necesito acceder a archivos de distinto tipo (imágenes, pdfs) que se encuentran dentro de la solución de mi proyecto. Traté de utilizar `Server.MapPath` pero me lanza una excepción, la cual menciona que `HttpContext.Current` es nulo.

Probé con `Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"img\logo.png")` y me devuelve una ruta apuntando hacia el disco local, pero no es lo que necesito.

Adjunto extracto del código:

```
if(condicion)
{
   string pathPdf = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"img\logo.png");
   emailService.AttachFile(pathPdf);
}
```

Básicamente es un servicio que envía un email con archivo adjunto al cumplirse una condición.

Alguna idea de cómo solucionarlo?

Comment: Te refieres a asp.net,winforms,wpf...?

Comment: ASP.Net master!

Comment: Ok..en principio con `Server.MapPath("~/img/logo.png")` deberías poder acceder. Prueba y nos comentas

Comment: Cómo mencione en la pregunta master, probé con `Server.MapPath` pero el Current se devuelve como nulo, por lo que me lanza una excepción

Comment: Intenta entonces con `Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, "img/logo.png");`

Comment: Tal vez sería bueno que incluyeras el código que tienes con un poco de contexto para entender mejor lo que haces. El hecho de que `HttpContext.Current` sea null estando en ASP.NET me indica de que tal vez estás haciendo algo un tanto inusual, y que a su vez tal vez requiera una solución menos usual.

Comment: @sstan Editada. @Pikoh, como notarás estoy obteniendo la ruta como me comentaste, la duda que me surge es si al momento de pasar a producción no me traerá conflicto con las `paths`. =/

Comment: Colega, formula bien tu pregunta... sería excelente también que nos adjuntaras el código que estas intentando y no te funciona, así podemos orientarnos mejor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando el código que estas ejecutando no corre dentro del thread principal, `HttpContext.Current` es nulo y no se puede acceder a `Server.MapPath`. En esos casos, una posible solución es usar [`HttpRuntume.AppDomainAppPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.httpruntime.appdomainapppath(v=vs.110).aspx). En tu caso sería algo como:

```
string path=Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, "img/logo.png");
```

Comment: Probado en distintos ambientes! Muchisimas gracias =)